# My R code is not plotting the visual correctly

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to recreate this in R visual in Power BI using columns and tables:

```
library(plotly)

dat <- data.frame(
    time = factor(c("Lunch","Dinner"), levels=c("Lunch","Dinner")),
    total_bill = c(14.89, 17.23)
)

p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=time, y=total_bill)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity")

p
```

Here is what I have come up with:

```
library(plotly)
   
p <- ggplot(dataset['Meal'],dataset['Number'], aes(x=time, y=total_bill)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity")
p
```

But I am getting errors. This is what the table looks like:

```
Meal    Number
Dinner  14.89
Lunch   17.23
```

For those wondering where 'dataset' comes from. In Power BI, I selected the R visual and it creates a small R widget with a text box where I can enter the script. Then it allows me to drag and drop columns from tables which are already in the report. Here is an image:

[image]

Notice how the columns are automatically defined when I drag the columns in.

```
# The following code to create a dataframe and remove duplicated rows is always executed and acts as a preamble for your script: 

# dataset <- data.frame(Meal, Number)
# dataset <- unique(dataset)

# Paste or type your script code here:
```

Comment: tbh my background is in Python. To create Python visuals that's what we would do in Power BI. I just assumed R may work in a similar way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to edit the x and y inputs in order to reproduce the example, but your issue seems to be a missing closing parenthesis on this line

```
time = factor(x,
```

This code gets me the result I think you're after

```
x<-c("Dinner", "Lunch")
y<-c(14.89,17.23)

dat <- data.frame(
  time = factor(x),
                total_bill = y
  )
  p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=time, y=total_bill)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity")
  p
```

Update:
Thanks for the additional info. I'm unfamiliar with Power BI, but it looks to me like the issue might be that the columns in 'dataset' might be unnamed (or at least it's unclear what the column names are). We can set the column names which should then allow us to plot as intended:

```
colnames(dataset)<- c("time", "total_bill") 

 p <- ggplot(data=dataset, aes(x=time, y=total_bill)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity")
  p
```

Comment: I think there is a slight misunderstanding. What I'd like to be able to do is reference the columns in the table rather than type the values.

Comment: Is the table already in the R environment? (as in, is it loaded from a csv file or something similar and able to be interacted with?)

If not, you'll need to explain what format the data is in order to find out how to import it.

If the data is available in the environment, what is the variable type? You probably don't need to separate the values out into x and y variables. You can reference columns of a object in data.frame() as above if the variable type is compatible.

Comment: I think I've just realised the issue, is 'dataset' the name of the table variable? If so I think this should do it:

ggplot(dataset, (aes(x=Meal, y=Number))+geom_bar(stat="identity")

Comment: I've added more information in the question section. It should make things a lot clearer

Comment: I've just tried the code above but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: I've edited my original answer, but I also spotted in your screenshot that it looks as though the column 'Number' might be being treated as text when (I assume) you want it as a number? As I say, I'm unfamiliar with power BI but thought it would be worthwhile to rule that out as a potential cause

Comment: Hi this solved it perfectly. It looks like I may need to rename it all the time.